# Pandas or python, loop through SQL queries held in a column in a dataframe, append the results in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which consists of 1000's of different SQL queries I would like to loop through and have the results of each appended in another dataframe, below is an example of 2 rows.

| index | SQLQuery |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | select comment from tablea where columna = 'x' and columnb = 'y' |
| 1 | select comment from tableb where columnc = 'w' and columnd = 'z' |

I believe it is along the lines of the following but I can't get it to work-

select_query = 'What should I set in here?'

```
df_list = []
for x in select_query:
  df = pd.read_sql(select_query, conn) 
  df_list.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: `pd.concat((pd.read_sql(select_query, conn) for select_query in df['SQlQuery']))` ?

Comment: Thnks this hs helped get me closer to what I need.

Comment: Just close? :P I thought it should answer this query